# how to make loading spinner javascript

Tags: javascript, html, ejs

I want to basically create a loading spinner for when my page is loading in javascript. Sometimes, the page takes long to load based on connection and I would just like to show a loading spinner while it loads.

I'm not sure where to start, I will show my main HTML/EJS code to show where I would need it. Thanks in advance for the help!

```js
$(window).load(function() {
    $('#loading').hide();
  });
```

```css
.loader {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 32px);
  left: calc(50% - 32px);
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  perspective: 800px;
}

.inner {
  position: absolute;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;  
}

.inner.one {
  left: 0%;
  top: 0%;
  animation: rotate-one 1s linear infinite;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #EFEFFA;
}

.inner.two {
  right: 0%;
  top: 0%;
  animation: rotate-two 1s linear infinite;
  border-right: 3px solid #EFEFFA;
}

.inner.three {
  right: 0%;
  bottom: 0%;
  animation: rotate-three 1s linear infinite;
  border-top: 3px solid #EFEFFA;
}

@keyframes rotate-one {
  0% {
    transform: rotateX(35deg) rotateY(-45deg) rotateZ(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateX(35deg) rotateY(-45deg) rotateZ(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes rotate-two {
  0% {
    transform: rotateX(50deg) rotateY(10deg) rotateZ(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateX(50deg) rotateY(10deg) rotateZ(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes rotate-three {
  0% {
    transform: rotateX(35deg) rotateY(55deg) rotateZ(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateX(35deg) rotateY(55deg) rotateZ(360deg);
  }
}
#loading {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
  opacity: 0.7;
  background-color : #0e086b;
  z-index: 99;
  text-align: center;
  }
#loading-image {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 240px;
  z-index: 100;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="loading">
  <div class="loader">
    <div class="inner one"></div>
    <div class="inner two"></div>
    <div class="inner three"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Comment: @NicoHaase  Sorry I pasted the wrong code into the question before lol. I've edited my question to show what I've tried. So far it just never stops spinning.

Comment: The issue here is that your loading spinner won't load until the page has loaded. Do you know what is making the page slow to load? Ideally you would separate out anything non-essential and load that after the document has rendered (and the spinner is visible)

Comment: @DBS sometimes the connection to the database is slow, but by slow I mean takes 2 seconds instead of 1. So in that little time in between, to make it more user friendly, I'd just like to put a loading spinner

Comment: Is it an Ajax call or is it just the whole page in general when you load it for the first time?

Comment: @epascarello the whole page in general

Comment: Why not check **why** the whole page loads slowly, and work on that instead?

Comment: You most likely ain't going to get a spinner to really work in this case.

Answer (score 1):

simply remove the anim !

on the real [`DOMContentLoaded` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event)

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) =>
  {
  let LoadAnim = document.getElementById('loading')
  document.body.remove(LoadAnim)
  }
);
```

> **sample code :**
> (simply click on snippet to stop the animation)

```js
document.body.onclick = () =>  // simulate DOMContentLoaded event
  {
  let LoadAnim = document.getElementById('loading')
  document.body.remove(LoadAnim)
  }
```

```css
#loading {
  display          : block;
  position         : fixed;
  top              : 0;
  left             : 0;
  width            : 100%;
  height           : 100%;
  background-color : #040030e7;
  z-index          : 99;
  }
#loading > div {
  position      : absolute;
  top           : calc(50% - 32px);
  left          : calc(50% - 32px);
  width         : 64px;
  height        : 64px;
  border-radius : 50%;
  perspective   : 800px;
  }
#loading > div > div {
  position      : absolute;
  box-sizing    : border-box;
  width         : 100%;
  height        : 100%;
  border-radius : 50%;  
  left          : 0%;
  top           : 0%;
  border-bottom : 3px solid #f5f125;
  }
#loading > div > div:nth-of-type(1) { animation : rotate-1 1s linear infinite;     }
#loading > div > div:nth-of-type(2) { animation : rotate-2 1s linear infinite .3s; }
#loading > div > div:nth-of-type(3) { animation : rotate-3 1s linear infinite .6s; }
@keyframes rotate-1 {
  0%   { transform: rotateX(35deg) rotateY(-45deg) rotateZ(0deg);   }
  100% { transform: rotateX(35deg) rotateY(-45deg) rotateZ(360deg); }
  }
@keyframes rotate-2 {
  0%   { transform: rotateX(50deg) rotateY(10deg) rotateZ(0deg);   }
  100% { transform: rotateX(50deg) rotateY(10deg) rotateZ(360deg); }
  }
@keyframes rotate-3 {
  0%   { transform: rotateX(35deg) rotateY(55deg) rotateZ(0deg);   }
  100% { transform: rotateX(35deg) rotateY(55deg) rotateZ(360deg); }
  }
```

```html
<div id="loading"> <!-- loading annimation-->
  <div> <div></div> <div></div> <div></div> </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this works good, however, it doesn't ever stop loading. is there a way around this?

Comment: @Gianluca do you load the data from your database with an AJAX request? In this case you must use the end of the AJAX loading and compose to stop the animation ...

Comment: no, I am using nodejs, so it is server side. It returns the data on the backend, and that passes it through when it renders the page

Comment: @Gianluca I have the feeling that there is no event sent ..
maybe try by placing the `.remove(...)` just in the last line of the last JS script put just before the `</body>` end tag?

Answer (score 1):

you can handle it manually. whenever you want to show a spinner you can call

```
$('#loading').show();
```

and to hide it after the ajax call use this in the callback function

```
$('#loading').hide();
```

The following solution will hide the spinner after 3 seconds, when the page loaded

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeout(function(){ $('#loading').hide(); }, 3000);
});
```

```css
.loader {
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50% - 32px);
  left: calc(50% - 32px);
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  perspective: 800px;
}

.inner {
  position: absolute;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;  
}

.inner.one {
  left: 0%;
  top: 0%;
  animation: rotate-one 1s linear infinite;
  border-bottom: 3px solid green;
}

.inner.two {
  right: 0%;
  top: 0%;
  animation: rotate-two 1s linear infinite;
  border-right: 3px solid green;
}

.inner.three {
  right: 0%;
  bottom: 0%;
  animation: rotate-three 1s linear infinite;
  border-top: 3px solid green;
}

@keyframes rotate-one {
  0% {
    transform: rotateX(35deg) rotateY(-45deg) rotateZ(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateX(35deg) rotateY(-45deg) rotateZ(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes rotate-two {
  0% {
    transform: rotateX(50deg) rotateY(10deg) rotateZ(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateX(50deg) rotateY(10deg) rotateZ(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes rotate-three {
  0% {
    transform: rotateX(35deg) rotateY(55deg) rotateZ(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotateX(35deg) rotateY(55deg) rotateZ(360deg);
  }
}
#loading {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
  opacity: 0.7;
  background-color: #fff;
  z-index: 99;
  text-align: center;
  }
#loading-image {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 240px;
  z-index: 100;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="loading">
  <div class="loader">
    <div class="inner one"></div>
    <div class="inner two"></div>
    <div class="inner three"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```